# Is PGI compiler supported for Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, compiling, fortran

I need to do some parallel computation with OpenACC on my GeForce GTX 1080Ti GPU.

Currently, my program is being compiled in serial with GCC Fortran compiler (gfortran). I want to know if it is possible to install PGI Compiler on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

If it is not possible, what would be better: to downgrade to an older Ubuntu version, or to compile with GCC OpenACC flags?

Thank you

Comment: I guess it's worth a try. PGI compilers worked with Ubuntu 17.10 https://www.pgroup.com/resources/docs/18.4/x86/pgi-install-guide/index.htm